# Configure gradle for sonarqube to work with Lombok

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, lombok

I read that in order SonarQube appropriate handles java classes annotated with Lombok, I need to define **sonar.java.libraries** property. But what is the value of this property? I have a gradle project. If I put build/lib/*.jar in the property, it doesn't solve the problem, i.e. SonarQube keeps to complain about private members without getters. So what is the necessary path? (My **sonar.java.libraries** is defined in the gradle configuration).

**Update**
I've added

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.2"
}
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

to my build.gradle, but this didn't solve my problem at all. I can build, but the sonarqube keeps to complain about not using private fields.

What should be added else?

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Do you use sonarqube scanner for gradle ? https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle If yes the libraries property should be automagically filled by the scanner relying on your gradle configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sonarqube + lombok = false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362965/sonarqube-lombok-false-positives)