# SonarQube doesn't see @RequiredArgsConstructor for @Service, any advice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, lombok

For all my @Component and @Service, I use

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired)).
```

It makes the code much cleaner an works just fine.

But SonarQube only accepts this for components. All fields in the service classes have the critical issue:

> "Annotate this member with "@Autowired", "@Resource", "@Inject", or
>   "@Value", or remove it."

Is there a solution to fix it or a workaround?
I don't want to disable the rule, because it helps sometimes.

My code:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class fooService {

private final FooDAO fooDAO; // Annotate this member with "@Aurowired"...

// rest of the class
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362965/sonarqube-lombok-false-positives)? It seems like a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can simply disable the rules you don't want in SonarQube, it's completely customizable to your needs.

And as of v 4.3 of Spring, you don't even need to put the `@Autowired` annotation if you have only one constructor, it is implicit, [see Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html). So you only need this :

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FooService {
  private final FooDAO fooDAO;
}
```

Comment: I may misunderstand your answer, but your first snippet is exactly what `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))` produces.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't see it was a Lombok annotation. So what I'm saying is you don't need the autowired, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like its fixed in the 6.3 version of SonarJava here:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3330