# Sonar + Lombok false positives on @Data annotation

Tags: java, sonarqube, lombok

I am getting a lot code smells from lombok generated code in Sonar. F.E.:

> Method Dto.hashCode() stores return result in local before immediately returning it

---

> Dto.equals(Object)
>   is excessively complex, with a cyclomatic complexity of 58

How can I point out sonar that this should be skipped from analyze?

UPDATE

I've tried it already. My `lombok.config` file in root directory is:

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = call
```

It doesn't helps

I've tried it already: [sonarqube + lombok = false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362965/sonarqube-lombok-false-positives)
I've updated: `sonar-project.properties` in root directory to:

```
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=build/classes
sonar.junit.reportPaths=build/test-results/test/
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=build/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec
sonar.java.libraries=.gradle/caches/**/lombok-*.jar
```

It doesn't work either.

---

Please don't close it. It is not duplication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sonarqube + lombok = false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362965/sonarqube-lombok-false-positives)

Comment: thanks @user7294900. I've also tried this solution. Did not help. I will update question

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. I am using sonar-scanner and figured out that it needs to set Lombok jar file using command line argument.

For example:

```
sonar-scanner -D sonar.java.libraries=/home/gitlab-runner/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.10/625fc0055674dff70dbc76efa36d0f2c89b04a24/lombok-1.18.10.jar
```

Now SonarQube does not show any issues related with Lombok annotations.

Comment: solved my problem, but the problem for me was  sonar.java.libraries=m2/repositories and my lombok jar was in m2/repositories/org/projectlombok/lombok/lombok-1.18.24.jar

Answer (score 1):

Methods generated by lombok need to be annotated with [@Generated](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Generated.html). Sonarqube will then ignore them.

Just add a file `lombok.config` in the project root directory, with the following content:

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation=true
```

Comment: Sorry done this already. I will update question. Did help only for code test coverage :(

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `lombok.jar` is well inside the directory referenced in the `sonar.java.libraries` property.

I had the same problem, I added the property but I had put a reference to the directory of my runtime package that did not contains the `lombok.jar`!

`lombok.jar` is used at compile time and useless at runtime so we avoid to add it inside this directory.