# How to tell to lombok the generated getter is an @Override

Tags: java, sonarqube, overriding, lombok

I'm using lombok in my project and I have an interface :

```
public interface MyInterface{

    Object getA()
}
```

And a class

```
@Getter
public class MyClass implements MyInterface{

      private Object a;

      private Object b

}
```

And i've checked the generated class and the method generated in the class is not `@Override`

I'm wondering how to add this annotation ? And what are the consequences of a missing `@Override` ?

It's maybe an another question but this code is analyzed by sonarqube and sonar say that private field a is never used.

I've already seen the subject about [sonarqube + lombok = false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362965/sonarqube-lombok-false-positives)

But In my case b doesn't create a false positive. So I don't think this is directly related

Do you see a solution to avoid this problems without reimplement getA() ?

Comment: just curious, why do you need it?

Comment: I have lot of class with a field named code. Theirs is currently  no common heritage between this class(and we don't want to) . For an utility class who detect change in a list of that type of entity we have create a common interface who define getCode.

Comment: And we want to use it in à bundle of class so avoiding implément each getter each time

Comment: This was a useful question since I've added Error Prone to my project and it's configured to mark functions which override and don't @Override as a build error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`onMethod` attribute](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) of the annotation to add any annotation you want to the generated method.

```
@Getter
public class MyClass implements MyInterface{
    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@Override))
    private Object a;
    private Object b
}
```

As a matter of style in this case, I would probably move the class-level `@Getter` to the other field. If there were `c`, `d`, `e` which should all use normal (no annotation) @Getter logic, I would leave it as above.

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface{
    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@Override))
    private Object a;
    @Getter
    private Object b
}
```

You may also want to [enable Lombok's generated annotations](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration). It will prevent some tools (coverage, static analysis, etc) from bothering to check Lombok's methods. Not sure if it will help in this case, but I pretty much have it enabled in all of my projects.

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `@Override` to a particular field by using `@Getter`'s `onMethod`.

e.g.

```
@Getter(onMethod = @__(@Override))
private Object a;
```

`@Override` has [no affect on the code itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html#:%7E:text=%40Override%20%40Override%20annotation%20informs%20the,discussed%20in%20Interfaces%20and%20Inheritance.&text=While%20it%20is%20not%20required,it%20helps%20to%20prevent%20errors.). It simply informs the compiler that the method is overriding a method from its superclass. The compiler will fail the build if the method does not override a method from a superclass.

Comment: That is a good point I hadn't thought about. I personally wouldn't do this, anyway. The annotation mostly helps against user error rather than generated code. Honestly, if I were to do something like this, I would explicitly declare the getter/setter and Override annotation to make it more obvious to other developers that this is overriding the superclass.

Comment: Adding the annotation via lombok is still protecting against some user error - it checks that an interface is present with that method. If the class is changed in the future so that the interface were removed, a build failure would give the developer making that change time to think "do I really need this field and method any more?" Without a build failure, they may get left in accidentally. But I probably wouldn't add it either, mostly because the syntax is ugly, I'd do what you said. Of course, all of that is conditional upon it actually working how you might optimistically think it should

Comment: In case you're curious, I just made a test project, and adding @Override this way does indeed work the way you'd want/hope

Answer (score 2):

A more general way to prevent false positives detections of missing @Override by *Error Prone* (or similar tools) is to configure Lombok to annotate its generated code with `@lombok.Generated`. This can be done - globally - by adding the following entry to Lombok's `lombok.config`:

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

Note that this is not a universal solution - the relevant tool needs to respect `@lombol.Generated` (or better, any `@*.Generated`) annotation.

Tools like `Jacoco` and `Error Prone` (very recently) already support it.